# CarrierWave crop file on Cloud (fog)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, cloudfiles, fog

I am trying to crop an image with CarrierWave and put it on the cloud fog(cloud_files). How can I do this? Will I have to download a copy as a tempfile, crop that, and then upload it back?

If the above steps are right, then how would I do them?

Answer (score 0):

I used this guys setup carrierwave + twitter-bootstrap + jquery-file-upload + JCrop

The example is an image gallery app that uses jcrop to crop the images and save back via carrierwave.

https://github.com/n0ne/Rails-Carrierwave-jQuery-File-Upload